# Karma/anglular, testing event listener on run

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, sinon, chai

Bit of a strange scenario for testing - I have a listener in my .run I would love to be able to test with karma, I am not sure if I am approaching this correctly and could use some advice

So it's basically just

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
 $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
     //functionality i would like to test in here
 });
```

I am wondering what the best way to tackle this would be to test? I was thinking if i Could get the locationchange to fire somehow that would be great, then i could expect a result back. I am using Karma/chai/sinon . Thanks!

Comment: You can in your test manually do a navigation `$location.path(url)`. Call $scope.$apply and then verify the logic inside the run function.

Answer (score 1):

First you need a spy on the function you need to test,
For exemple you have a 'config' service with 'setConfig' function :

```
spyOn(config, 'setConfig');
```

Then you change the location path :

```
location.path('/route1');
```

Then you emit the event $stateChangeSuccess

```
$rootScope.$emit('$stateChangeSuccess');
```

And the test may be for example :

```
expect(config.setConf).toHaveBeenCalledWith('param1', '/route1');
```